# Vulkan Fence already in use by another submission

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm trying to create a game using Vulkan and C++. I've got to a part where I use multiple command buffers with threading - or so I thought if I'm doing it correctly.

Now, I'm having a problem with fence. The console-I added a validation layer-says "Fence 0x21 is already in use by another submission."

I never used the fence in other functions.

The code below is the draw function. I call this function in a loop.

```
update_ubo (); // this function just writes uniform data on the uniform buffer in the local device.

uint32_t image_index = 0;
VkResult result = vkAcquireNextImageKHR (device, swapchain, numeric_limits <uint64_t>::max (), semaphore_image_avail, fence, &image_index);

// I hope I'm using multithreading correctly.
// all command buffers recorded in record_commandbuffers function are secondary command buffers.
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(thread::hardware_concurrency ())
for (int64_t i = 0 ; i < (int64_t) vkthreads.size () ; i ++)
    record_commandbuffers (vkthreads [i], framebuffers [image_index]);

VkCommandBufferBeginInfo cmdbuf_info = {
    VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO,
    nullptr,
    VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT,
    nullptr
};

VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderpass_begin = {
    VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO,
    nullptr,
    renderpass,
    framebuffers [image_index],
    {
        { 0, 0 },
        swapchain_extent
    },
    1,
    &clear_value
};

vkBeginCommandBuffer (pcmdbuf, &cmdbuf_info);
vkCmdBeginRenderPass (pcmdbuf, &renderpass_begin, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_SECONDARY_COMMAND_BUFFERS);

for (size_t i = 0 ; i < vkthreads.size () ; i ++)
    vkCmdExecuteCommands (pcmdbuf, (uint32_t) vkthreads [i].cmdbufs.size (), vkthreads [i].cmdbufs.data ());

vkCmdEndRenderPass (pcmdbuf);
vkEndCommandBuffer (pcmdbuf);

if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR)
    window_changed ();
else if (result != VK_SUCCESS && result != VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR)
    throw exception ("Could not acquire next images.");

VkPipelineStageFlags pipeline_flags [] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT };
VkSubmitInfo submit_info = {
    VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO,
    nullptr,
    1,
    &semaphore_image_avail,
    pipeline_flags,
    1,
    &pcmdbuf,
    1,
    &semaphore_render_finished
};

if (vkQueueSubmit (graphics_queue, 1, &submit_info, fence))
    throw exception ("Could not submit information into the graphics queue.");

while (vkWaitForFences (device, 1, &fence, VK_TRUE, (uint64_t)100000000) == VK_TIMEOUT)
    ;

vkResetFences (device, 1, &fence);

VkSwapchainKHR swapchains [] = { swapchain };
VkPresentInfoKHR present_info = {
    VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR,
    nullptr,
    1,
    &semaphore_render_finished,
    1,
    swapchains,
    &image_index,
    nullptr
};

result = vkQueuePresentKHR (present_queue, &present_info);

if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR)
    window_changed ();
else if (result != VK_SUCCESS && result != VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR)
    throw exception ("Could not presnet the queue.");
```

P.S. FPS dropped significantly when I added multithreading (2000 fps to 210 fps, in debug release), and CPU usage went up significantly, which is expected. Should I care about FPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the same fence to AcquireNextImage and QueueSubmit without waiting in between. You only need to pass it to QueueSubmit as the semaphore will take care of any required sync. Just pass VK_NULL_HANDLE to the acquireNexImage.

Paying such a huge cost of 5 ms per frame penalty due to threading overhead does seem a bit steep I'd expect a millisecond or two due to scheduler though it depends on how you are actually multithreading. But as long as total per frame remains under 16 ms for 60 fps it's no big deal.

Comment: Well, FPS increased to 520 when I did some tinkling. But thank you.

Comment: @schmzmtl: Please stop measuring time in framerate. Measure frame time as actual time.